# How can I show and hide the form in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html form which is supposed to appear only after clicking a submit button. I have added simple JavaScript to display the same on click.

Intention is show the update form on click of the button above it. Can anyone help me out to find what I did wrong?

```js
function showForm() {
  alert('Form has been submitted');
  document.getElementByClass(UpdateForm - section).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.UpdateForm-section.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="delete" class="button-1" value="Update" onclick="showForm();" />
<br><br><br>
<!-- Update details form here -->
<div>
  <form action="" method="post" class="UpdateForm-section">
    <label>Car Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="ev_name" placeholder="Model name"><br>
    <label>Manufacturer</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="ev_manufacturer" placeholder="Brand name"><br>
    <label>Year</label>
    <input type="number" value="" name="ev_year" placeholder="YYYY"><br>
    <label>Battery size</label>
    <input type="number" value="" step="any" name="ev_battery" placeholder="Capacity in Kwh"><br>
    <label>Range</label>
    <input type="number" value="" name="ev_range" placeholder="Range in Km"><br>
    <label>Cost</label>
    <input type="number" value="" name="ev_cost" placeholder="Price in €"><br>
    <label>Power</label>
    <input type="number" value="" name="ev_power" placeholder="Power in Kw"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="update_submit" value="Update details" name="submit_button" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `getElementByClass`. It should be `getElementsByClassname`, plus you'd need quotes around the name as it's a string. Also, `.UpdateForm-section.hidden` won't select anything since the form doesn't have a .hidden class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below changes in your code.

**In CSS:**
remove `.hidden` from `.UpdateForm-section.hidden`

**In JS:**
use `querySelector` instead of `getElementByClass` and wrap the name of the class in quotes.

**Wokring code:**

```js
function showForm() {
  alert('Form has been submitted');
  document.querySelector('.UpdateForm-section').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.UpdateForm-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="delete" class="button-1" value="Update" onclick="showForm();" />
<br><br><br>
<!-- Update details form here -->
<div>
  <form action="" method="post" class="UpdateForm-section">
    <label>Car Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="ev_name" placeholder="Model name"><br>
    <label>Manufacturer</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="ev_manufacturer" placeholder="Brand name"><br>
    <label>Year</label>
    <input type="number" value="" name="ev_year" placeholder="YYYY"><br>
    <label>Battery size</label>
    <input type="number" value="" step="any" name="ev_battery" placeholder="Capacity in Kwh"><br>
    <label>Range</label>
    <input type="number" value="" name="ev_range" placeholder="Range in Km"><br>
    <label>Cost</label>
    <input type="number" value="" name="ev_cost" placeholder="Price in €"><br>
    <label>Power</label>
    <input type="number" value="" name="ev_power" placeholder="Power in Kw"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="update_submit" value="Update details" name="submit_button" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That works like charm! Thanks a ton Ankit. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have the following approach: define a desired style when your element will be shown:

```
.UpdateForm-section {  // here we set the default style of the div -> not displayed
    display: none;
}
.UpdateForm-section.active {  // here the CSS selector is stronger, so it will override the previous statement
        display: block;
}
```

Then in your javascript, you just add the "active" class to the element when you want it to show:

```
function showForm() {
   alert('Form has been submitted');
   document.querySelector(".UpdateForm-section").classList.add('active');  // Prefer to use an id to select an unique element to avoid miss coding
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save your form in a variable, and you can easyly change it after it. You will need to remove `.hidden` from your css.

You need to use `form[0]`, because when you make `getElementsByClassName`, you are getting an array:

```
function showForm() {
    alert('Form has been submitted');
    var form = document.getElementsByClassName("UpdateForm-section");
    form[0].style.display = 'block'
}
```